# Firestore Reads Billing Explanation

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How many reads occur/billed for if the query for a stream requests, for example, 100 documents but the cache only contains 80 of those documents requested by the query since 10 new documents were added to firestore that fall into the query and 10 documents no longer fall into the query due to a limit constraint set on the snapshot request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a query reaches the server, the cache is not used.  A query for 100 documents will return 100 documents, and cost 100 document reads, no matter what the cache contains.

I suggest reading [this](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/the-secrets-of-firestores-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-revealed-29dd7a38a82b) for more information about how the cache works.

Comment: I should rephrase, I'm listening to query results as a stream, so latest 100 documents are listened to on the stream, so no new query should be issued. I'm trying to understand from firestore website: "When you listen to the results of a query, you are charged for a read each time a document in the result set is added or updated." My concern is because of the limit on the stream documents are removed from the result set as new documents are added.

Comment: You're only charged for changed documents.  Everything else is retained in memory and has nothing to do with the document cache on disk.

Comment: Just so I understand correctly, once a document is read once at anytime it is kept in memory forever and if that document is never updated ANY future query requests containing that document will not count towards a read for that document?

Comment: There is no such thing as "kept in memory forever".  If you have a listener, the results are kept for only as long as that listener is added.

Comment: Ok, so every time that listener is initialized it will get charged for 100 document reads?